# Java - how to replace file contents?

Tags: java

I have a file that contains only a very small amount of information that needs to be updated periodically.  In other words, I want to truncate the file before writing to it.  The easiest solution I found was to delete and create it again as shown here:

```
File myFile = new File("path/to/myFile.txt");
myFile.delete();
myFile.createNewFile();
// write new contents
```

This 'works' fine, but is there a better way?

Comment: Do you care about preserving consistency of your file? If you do, there may be a better answer than in the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to delete the file and recreate one. If you are writing to the file, for instance using `PrintWriter`, it will overwrite your current file content.

Example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
      PrintWriter prw= new PrintWriter (“MyFile.txt”);
      prw.println("These text will replace all your file content");          
      prw.close();
 }
```

It will only append to the end of the file if you use the overloaded version of the PrintWriter constructor:

```
PrintWriter prw= new PrintWriter (new FileOutputStream(new File("MyFile.txt"), true));
//true: set append mode to true
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below example, the "false" causes the file to be overwritten, true would cause the opposite.

```
File file=new File("C:\Path\to\file.txt");
DataOutputStream outstream= new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,false));
String body = "new content";
outstream.write(body.getBytes());
outstream.close();
```